# Use a function in another function in shell

Tags: function, shell

```
Type()
{
    if [ -d $1 ]
        then
            return 1
    elif [ -e $1 ]
        then
            return 2
    else
            return 0
    fi
}

Types()
{
    local arg1 arg2
    for arg1 in $@
        do
            arg2=$(Type $arg1)
            if [ arg2 -eq 1 ]
                then
                    echo "$arg1 est un répertoire."
            elif [ arg2 -eq 2 ]
                then
                    echo "$arg1 n est pas un répertoire."
            else
                    echo "$arg1 ne correspond à aucune entrée du répertoire."
            fi
    done
}
```

I don't know how can I use the function 'Type' in 'Types'. I tried "arg2=$(Type $arg1)" bur it doesn't seem to work. What's the correct syntax please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the function with `$(Type ...)`, then you can change the `return ...` statements to `echo ...` (not `exec echo ...`, which does something else). If you want to keep the `return ...` statements in `Type()`, then you need to do something like `Type ...; arg2=$?` to test the return code from `Type()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return 1
```

Bash functions often return values through their standard output. For example, you could use something like this instead:

```
exec echo 1    # sends 1 to the standard output and then ends the function
```

Alternatively, you could return an integer between 0 and 255 as an exit code (as you are trying to do). If you choose to do so, you need to do:

```
Type $arg1
arg2=$?        # obtains exit code of last command/function executed
```

However, if you need to return an array, you must use a global variable. You may want to refer to the [Complex Functions and Function Complexities](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html) section of the *Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide* for examples of this method.

Comment: Thanks ! I used the last option.